Spectrum of Compact Hermitian Operator Accumulating at 0 From Both Directions
I'm getting into spectral theory and I'm wondering if someone could give an example of a Hilbert space $H$ and a compact hermitian operator $T$ on $H$ whose spectrum $\sigma(T)$ has both a positive and negative subsequence tending to 0? Moreover, could someone give me intuition for when this behavior occurs? Forgive me if this is obvious or ill-posed, it's just a little curiosity I had while reading about $C^*\text{-algebras}$.

Any compact Hermitian operator with both infinitely many positive and infinitely many negative eigenvalues work (since the positive eigenvalues necessarily form a sequence that converges to $0$ and the same holds for negative eigenvalues). For example, $T: l^2 \to l^2$ defined by $Te_n = \frac{1}{n}e_n$ when $n$ is even and $Te_n = -\frac{1}{n}e_n$ when $n$ is odd.

Awesome! Thank you!
